# Function order not clear in C++?

Tags: c++

I am executing the below program in C++, but does not compile. Please help to find the issue

```
#include<iostream>
class A;
void showA(A& x) {
    // Since showA() is a friend, it can access
    // private members of A
    std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a;
}
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A() {a = 0;}
    friend void showA(A& x); // global friend function
};



int main()
{
    A a;
    showA(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me below compilation error:

```
 In function 'void showA(A&)':
7:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'
:cout << "A::a=" << x.a;
                           ^
3:7: note: forward declaration of 'class A'
 class A;
       ^
```

Comment: You don't execute a program that does not compile. Just move the definition of `showA` after the class. **Solved.**

Comment: Hello, please note that: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

```
class A;
void showA(A& x) {
    // Since showA() is a friend, it can access
    // private members of A
    std::cout << "A::a=" << x.a;
}
```

We don't know that `A` will be a friend. We don't even know that `A` will have a member. You can not access members of an incomplete type. Trying to do so is *invalid use of incomplete type*.

Solution: Make the type complete (i.e. define the class) before accessing members.